# Moving from Unix makefile to GNU makefile (on Linux)

Tags: linux, make

just a quick question in case anyone can spot something obvious.

The following line in a Makefile works fine on Unix but gives an "empty variable name" error when using make on  Gnu/Linux. I haven't looked at this stuff for 15 years.

The line is:

```
$(PROJ_LIBS)            := OBJECTSVAR   = tools_OBJS
```

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: The shell does not matter as it's a Makefile and the fragment that you show wouldn't be executed by a shell anyway. Does the Makefile set the variable `PROJ_LIBS` to anything? I'm assuming it doesn't as GNU `make` complains with "empty variable name". What Unix did you run this on previously? The assignment assigns the string `OBJECTSVAR = tools_OBJS` to the variable named by `$(PROJ_LIBS)`, i.e. to the variable whose name is the value of the `PROJ_LIBS` variable.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, that's not how it works. In Solaris make that syntax means set "set `OBJECTSVAR` to `tools_OBJS` only when processing the `$(PROJ_LIBS)` targets". I have no idea if GNU make offers anything similar.

Comment: Hopefully @schily will chime in, he should know more about it.

Comment: Just fetch a recent `schilytools` tarball and compile. You then get a portable version of `make` and `dmake` from Solaris that supports the conditional macro assignment you mentioned in your question. See http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/make.1s.html and http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/sunpromake.html

Comment: It is PROJ_LIBS not being set to anything under some circumstances. Thanks very much for all your help.

Comment: @Hobbes1218 what is the origin of your `Makefile`? Note that conditional macro assignments assume a make target to the left side or `:=` and every `make` call has a target.